# Obscure links to promote service

Tags: discussion, spam-handling

There's an [interesting question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813324/ubuntu-16-04-is-slow-has-poor-performance-why) (*link for 10k'rs only*) that was posted recently.  On face value, it looks like a valid post.  It asks a valid ubuntu question, but if you look a bit closer, it has a link to some real estate software site on the `t` in the word `installed` in the first line of the post.

My question is, what should I do in a case like this?  Do I flag for deletion?  Do I try editing it out and face potential roll-back wars?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Good catch! You should flag this as spam since it is clearly spam. The OP is trying to hide their spam in a valid-sounding question.

Actually, for such hidden things, a custom mod flag might be a better choice. Explain that it is hidden spam. Otherwise, the mod who handles the flag could easily miss it.

In this particular case, I found the text of the question in a forum post [here](http://exceptionin.com/q/ubuntu-16-04-is-slow-has-poor-performance-why-2). The spammer simply copied it and added the spam link.

I've now deleted the post, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Here's another one by the same user: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803906/ubuntu-15-10-after-apt-get-upgrade-flashing-colored-dots.   You'll look hard to find the link unless you go to `edit`.

Comment: Ok, of his 7 post, only 3 don't have links.  However, some of his links aren't clickable because he put them inside backticks or codeblocks.

Comment: @anonymous2 yes, but they're still visible to search engines, presumably. I have now destroyed the user but I'll bet you the three that don't have links used to have them until someone edited them out.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Much appreciated!

Comment: Should that user be advised against doing this? Any measures to be taken beyond deletion?

Comment: @luchonacho the "user" is most likely a spam bot taking random forum posts, injecting spam and posting them here. If they are human, they are already well aware that this is not allowed. Otherwise, why go to the trouble of hiding the spam link? No, this user knows exactly what they're doing. There's no point in warning them.

Comment: @terdon I'm curious, is this behavior actually boosting the Google score of the spammer's website?

Answer (score 13):

This is one of those cases where I personally would flag for moderator's intervention because this is not so obvious of a case. Explain clearly that the post is spam and is disguised, point where the link is placed.

Comment: Very good point.